# Не работает http-proxy-middleware

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, proxy, axios

Не работает прокси из npm-пакета "http-proxy-middleware".Настраивал следуя документации.

**Вот код, который относится к прокси:**

*Код из файла сервера*:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const auth = require('../routes/auth');

app.use('/auth', [
  auth,
  createProxyMiddleware({
    target: `http://localhost:${PORT}`,
    changeOrigin: true,
  }),
]);
```

Код из файла API:

```
const axios = require('axios').default;

registration = async (data) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('auth/registration', data);
      return `Success: ${response.data.message}`;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

*В терминале пишет:*

```
[HPM] Proxy created: /  -> http://localhost:5000
Server is working on port 5000...
```

А при нажатии на кнопку отправки данных в консоле браузера пишет:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/auth/registration 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: `createProxyMiddleware` у вас используется на стороне фронтенда или сервера? как устроено ваше приложение?

Comment: @nörbörnën https://github.com/Eugen-www/productivio

Comment: я так понимаю, у вас стандартное реактовское приложение, которое в development режиме поднято на 3000 порту. и бекенд, поднятый на 5000 порту. зачем же вы делаете на бэкенде, в обработчике запроса, настройку проксирования этого запроса на фронтенд-сервер?

Comment: @nörbörnën так я же с фронта  делаю POST-запрос на сервер для регистрации пользователя и на бэкенде использую http-proxy-middleware [https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware]

Comment: ‘и на бэкенде использую http-proxy-middleware’ - зачем? какую задачу решает использование http-proxy-middleware?